# Is it a right practice to place more than one function with return inside the Python class definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Here is the code for finding the area of triangle , in which i have initialized  the dimensions of triangle in the `def __init__`  and also i need its area to be initialized for these initial dimensions, for this i have placed `self.a1` in the `def __init__` also. A Function `def tarea()` is returning the value to `self.a1` in the `__init__` function. An another function `def getarea()` is inside the class definition for returning the area of triangle , when the dimensions of triangle is set . Just need to know if this task can be implemented in more efficient manner? To write two functions with return inside a class definition is ok ?

```
class triangle:

    def __init__(self, sa1, sa2, sa3 ):
        self.s1 = sa1
        self.s2 = sa2
        self.s3 = sa3
        self.a1 = self.tarea()

    def sets1(self, ss1):
        self.s1 = ss1

    def sets2(self, ss2):
        self.s2 = ss2

    def sets3(self, ss3):
        self.s3 = ss3 

    def tarea(self):
        a = (self.s1 + self.s2 +self.s3)/2
        return (a*(a - self.s1)*(a-self.s2)*(a-self.s3))**0.5

    def getarea(self):
        self. a1 = self.tarea()
        return self.a1

tri = triangle(3,4,5)
print("Area of triangle=", tri.a1)
tri.sets1(4)
tri.sets2(5)
tri.sets3(6)
print("Area of triangle with another values",f'{tri.getarea():.2f}')
```

Comment: Yes, it's fine to have multiple functions with `return` statements in a class. No, this is an overcomplicated implementation of a triangle class. `a1`, `sets*` and `getarea` can all be omitted and `tarea` could simply be declared as `@property`.

Comment: This probably rather belongs to `code review`, I'm personally not a big fan of too many setters and getters especially if it's not total clear what they set and get. So depends what you want to use this `triangle` class for...

Comment: @po.pe actually explicity getters / setters that only get/set public attributes are an antipattern in Python

Answer (score 0):

I would define the area as a `property` that computes the area based on the current sides.

```
class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, sa1, sa2, sa3 ):
        self.s1 = sa1
        self.s2 = sa2
        self.s3 = sa3

    @property
    def area(self):
        a = (self.s1 + self.s2 +self.s3)/2
        return (a*(a - self.s1)*(a-self.s2)*(a-self.s3))**0.5
```

If you consider the area to expensive to calculate on-demand each if the sides haven't changed, you can cache the area. We make each of the sides a property that can invalidate the cache when a side changes.

The boilerplate-heavy version:

```
class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, sa1, sa2, sa3 ):
        self._s1 = sa1
        self._s2 = sa2
        self._s3 = sa3
        self._area = None
        # We could also use the setters to set self.s1 = sa1,
        # etc, and let them initialize self._area to None.

    @property
    def s1(self):
        return self._s1

    @s1.setter
    def s1(self, value):
        self._s1 = value
        self._area = None

    @property
    def s2(self):
        return self._s2

    @s2.setter
    def s2(self, value):
        self._s2 = value
        self._area = None

    @property
    def s3(self):
        return self._s3

    @s3.setter
    def s3(self, value):
        self._s3 = value
        self._area = None

    @property
    def area(self):
        if self._area is None:
            self._area = self._compute_area()
        return self._area

    def _compute_area(self):
        a = (self.s1 + self.s2 +self.s3)/2
        return (a*(a - self.s1)*(a-self.s2)*(a-self.s3))**0.5
```

A lighter version, without getting into a full-blown descriptor implementation.

```
def make_side_property(name):
    def get(self):
        return getattr(self, name)

    def set(self, value):
        setattr(self, name, value)
        self._area = None

    return property(get, set)


class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, sa1, sa2, sa3 ):
        self.s1 = sa1
        self.s2 = sa2
        self.s3 = sa3
        # Here we do let the setters initialize self._area

    s1 = make_side_property("_s1")
    s2 = make_side_property("_s2")
    s3 = make_side_property("_s3")

    @property
    def area(self):
        if self._area is None:
            self._area = self._compute_area()
        return self._area

    def _compute_area(self):
        a = (self.s1 + self.s2 +self.s3)/2
        return (a*(a - self.s1)*(a-self.s2)*(a-self.s3))**0.5
```

Comment: you may want to either use `_set_side()` or remove it ;-)

Comment: That was left over from a worse attempt at reducing the boilerplate, and I forgot to delete it before posting.

Comment: Wow, this is overkill. If you're super duper worried about computing `area` once I'd just make the class immutable and make it a `cached_property`...

Comment: Based on the original question, making the class immutable isn't necessarily an option.